# How do dynamic web-apps work?

Tags: http, rest, web-applications, xmlhttprequest

Well, I get that the basic idea how internet works : client sends request, server sends back a response.
But I was trying to develop a rails app and I ran into things like RESTful architecture, http requests(GET, POST etc), xhr requests. So, I thought it would be great if someone could give a detailed explanation what these things are and how do they come together in a CRUD web-app.

Comment: I think your question "How do dynamic web-apps work" is a different question than the details of your question suggest.  A dynamic web app as described http://www.serverwatch.com/tutorials/article.php/2199701/What-does-Dynamic-Web-Application-Really-Mean-.htm  need not have the features you list (restful, xhr requests, etc)

Answer (score 6):

Ok I'll give this a shot:

> Why use a RESTful architecture?

For a lot of web applications these days, people are building a REST API in between the database and the application.

The REST API provides data to the web application and it can be called either on the server side (before a page is sent to the user) or on the client side (after a user has downloaded a page).

It can also be leveraged by future projects. For example, imagine your website takes off and you want a native mobile app as well. You can re-use your existing REST API to accomplish that.

> HTTP verbs

For a long time the only HTTP verbs (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) most web developers used were GET and POST.

REST services that deal with data expanded upon existing HTTP verbs that usually didn't get much action. So if you want to delete an object with a REST call, you would use the DELETE verb as an example.

The HTTP verbs just give your REST service a more intuitive way to operate on data.

> XHR Requests

XHR Request (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) - is just a way of making an AJAX call. The idea is that the client (the person that gets your web page) will make direct calls to your REST service.

The big difference though is that the call is made "in the background" - or in other words - without a page refresh.  Think of how Gmail works when you get new emails.  You don't notice the entire page refreshing in the browser.  It just provides a nicer user experience.

> How do they work together?

When making a web application these days, it's common to have a REST service/API that serves your data from the database.  Then when accessing that REST service from your web application, you can decide whether or not you want to make those calls server side (from Java/C#/Ruby/whatever) or from the client side (Javascript).

There are challenges with each approach, but hopefully that helps.

Comment: As a complement to this answer, please note that your application can also be RESTful (not just your API), and that, in a Resource Oriented Architecture, both the application for users and the API are two representations of the same resources. It's hard to explain this in a few lines but there are wonderful books about that such as : L. Richardson, S. Ruby. RESTful Web Services. O'Reilly, 2007.

Answer (score 0):

For a Rail CRUD project i would suggest you take a look at this tutorial (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) and it will show you a basic web app, that has CRUD operation ,after that you could try experimenting to adding REST API to make it possible to create blog post or adding comments to a post using REST API. You can find a lots of resources here (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#sec-rest_api)

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to answer directly your question. However, the client-server relationship can be very simple. Some time ago I tried to understand how it worked in practice and did this from the Java Perspective. So wrote some code to that and I have been using this for a while already. The basic idea is that I have some kind of Client Application that after getting some date, it sends to the Server and the server saves it in a file. Maybe it can help you to understand how you should do yours:

**Client Side:**

```
         try {
              // Establish connection with the server
              Socket socket = new Socket(host, 8000);

              // Create an output stream to the server
              ObjectOutputStream toServer =new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
              String playerIPClean=socket.getLocalAddress().getHostAddress();
              String s=""; 
# you can put your data here in this string and send everything  in this string 
# (afterwords you split the data)

              toServer.writeObject(s);
              toServer.close();
              socket.close();
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
              System.err.println(ex);
            }
```

The client sent a request to send a string!
**Server side:**

```
      public TheServer() {
        try {
          // Create a server socket
          ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8000);
          System.out.println("Server started ");
          PrintWriter outputToFile=null;
          while (true) {
            // Listen for a new connection request
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

            // Create an input stream from the socket
            inputFromClient =
              new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            // Read from input
            Object object = inputFromClient.readObject();
            textContent=object.toString();
            textContent=object.toString();
            String fileNameComposer;
            fileNameComposer=fileName+"rew"+reward+"."+expName+"prize";
    //        System.out.println(fileName);
            try{
                outputToFile=new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileNameComposer));
                outputToFile.println(object);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Caught IOException: "
                                    +  e.getMessage());

           } finally {
                inputFromClient.close();
                if (outputToFile != null) {
                    System.out.println("Closing PrintWriter");
                    outputToFile.close();
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("PrintWriter not open");
                }
           }


            System.out.println("A new object is stored");
//          System.out.println(object);
          }
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {

          try {
//          inputFromClient.close();
    //        outputToFile.close();
          }
          catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      }
```

Off course, the server application should be continuously running to accept anything (I took some time to understand this). The server accepts the request, receives the string and saves it. This idea is quite easy in Java. Actually the Liang's Java book helped me a lot to understand this stuff in Java.